# Toggle bool every 0.5f?

Tags: c#, toggle, modulo

I am currently trying to toggle whether or not an object is active every fifth increment of a variable called `multiplier`. This variable is incremented by a value of `0.1f` every now and then during the update process. Essentially from `1.0f` to `1.4f` it should be inactive, then from `1.5f` to `1.9f` it should be active. Likewise, from `2.0f` to `2.4f` it should be inactive again.

I had the idea to use modulus to toggle this value, but I can't seem to get it to work. The code below (and many other variations I've tried) leaves the object inactive from `1.0f` to `1.4f` then active for `1.5f` and back to inactive from `1.6f` to `1.9f` continuing that process.

```
bool modResult = (int)((multiplier * 10) % 5) == 0;
Active = multiplier > 1.0f && modResult && !Active;
```

---

How can I toggle my `bool` at every fifth increment without an additional variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind, it appears that the late hour is slowing my thought process. Turns out the issue is elsewhere, after breaking it down to the following, the same issue is still occurring so I'm diving into that. The following will toggle every fifth:

```
if ((int)((multiplier * 10) % 5) == 0)
    Active = !Active;
```

Comment: I would suggest, though, that you work with integers instead of keeping it in floating-point. You never know when multiplying by 10 is going to introduce digits at 10^-51 (seen it happen!). Integers won't fail you. If you still need it in terms of tenths, keep two variables.